# Реализация интерфейса приема файла из печати java

Tags: java, текст, печать

Есть кассовое приложение, у которого единственный интерфейс вывода данных - печать чека через форму как в chrome, есть возможность сохранить файл в pdf, либо отправить на чековый принтер. Есть ли какая-то возможность создать в этом меню строку, чтобы отправить текст не на принтер, а в моё Java приложение, которое уже обработает текст и отправит мне по сети нужные данные?

Работаю курьером, хочу немного облегчить себе жизнь.....

Подскажите в какую сторону копать, какую литературу и библиотеки курить?

Answer (score 0):

Есть реализации [LPD](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_Printer_Daemon) в Java. Далее можно самому добавить принтер в Windows, который использует LPR протокол печати на указанном LPD принтере. Он принимает ответ в виде потока байт, которым далее можно манипулировать.

---

См. [Create a virtual printer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4312686/8280225).